# Not able to use customDirective with mat-menu-item

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use myCustomDirective with mat-menu-item directive. But myCustomDirective is not getting applied on the element with mat-menu-item. And it is not throwing any error also.

I've tried using ng-container and ng-template to use both myCustomDirective and mat-menu-item on different element, but it didn't work.

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" myCustomDirective="x">
  <button mat-menu-item>
     item1
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item myCustomDirective="y">
    item2
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item myCustomDirective="z">
     item3
  </button>
</mat-menu>


@Directive({
    selector: '[myCustomDirective]'
})
export class MyCustomDirective {

       @Input() myCustomDirective: string;

        constructor( private element: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer2
        ) { }

        ngAfterViewInit() {
            console.log(this.myCustomDirective);
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 
               'border-style', 'dashed');
        }
}
```

Expected: MyCustomDirective should be applied on mat-menu-item
Actual: MyCustomDirective is not getting applied

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmef9y It is working fine in this stackblitz

Comment: Thanks @Chellppan I don't know for some reason in my project it is not working and  it is not throwing error. Atleast now i know it is not the issue related to mat-menu

Comment: Did you include the directive in NgModule?

Comment: I have a similar problem: my directive adds a child element of the button, but it becomes a sibling of the button.